# Laravel MessageBag undefined property

Tags: php, laravel

On every page of the site I have a a newsletter signup box. If there is an error, it shows using the following:

```
<?php if($errors->newsletter->first('emailAddress')) : ?>
    <span class="input-error-notification">{{$errors->newsletter->first('emailAddress');}}</span>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Which works fine, for the most part. However, as soon as I have a page that requires other errors I get the error `Undefined property: Illuminate\Support\MessageBag::$newsletter`.

In a customer registration controller I have the following:

```
$message = new Illuminate\Support\MessageBag;
$message->add('codeError', 'Invalid confirmationCode code. Please click the link in the email we sent you.');

return View::make('components.message')->withErrors($message);
```

This gives me the error. I know I am overwriting the default global `MessageBag`, which I don't want to do.

I also get the error if I do not create a new `MessageBag`.

Anybody have any ideas what can be done here? I can't find anything relating to this.

Comment: Where did you define $newsletter?

Comment: @KelvinKyaw in another Controller. If I remove the `->withErrors(...)` it all works as it should, so I don't believe that this is the problem. Laravel allows you to name MessageBags, and that error only exists when the newsletter form has been submit and returned with a validation error.

Comment: Let me know result after you try this way. ->withErrors($message->all);

Comment: @KelvinKyaw I have the same result, unfortunately. It looks like I am overwriting the default Instance of the validator Instantiation. Laravel automatically Instantiates the Validator when you call withErrors and I'm confusing it. Looks like I will have to find a new way to do what I want. Thank you for your help though :)